# How to generate AWS credential report for all accounts in an organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-java-sdk, aws-sts, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am looking to generate a AWS credential report for all the accounts under an organization. Is there any way to generate the consolidated report of accounts.

I know we can generate a credential report per account (one) under an organization as per the AWS documentation

**https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_getting-report.html**

The same way can we generate a credential report for all the accounts in an organization with single root user? or if we can create a cross account will it help us to get all the credentials in the assumed role account?

Comment: Will the cross account role helps us to get the details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no AWS Organizations integration for the IAM service action *generate-credential-report*. You can look up all integrations in the docs: *AWS services that you can use with AWS Organizations* [1]. It looks like there is an integration for *service last accessed data* and *IAM access analyzer*.

That is, for the time being, you can probably just iterate over all your accounts and call *generate-credential-report* [2]. There is a python tool on GitHub that simplifies this strategy. [3]
I guess you can adjust this tool to serve your needs.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_integrate_services_list.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/generate-credential-report.html
[3] https://github.com/lloesche/aws-user-report